# Can you make JEditorPanes understand advanced HTML and CSS?

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

Is it possible to make a `JEditorPane` understand more advanced HTML and CSS?
I mean, when you enter HTML or CSS such as `<button>`, `<progress>`, or most other tags, it does not understand them. Is there any way to make it understand and display more complex and advanced coding? If it is, how would I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218572/java-html5-alternative-to-jeditorpane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Java 7 EE has HTML5 functionality although I'm not sure about specific tags. Also, there are external packages, like [one from Intel freely available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23205151/how-to-add-html5-tag-attributes-to-javax-swing-text-html-html-attribute) and you can always extend the functionality yourself in some way or another.

**Edit: addendum to my 2nd suggestion (implementing the topic in the linked question)**

The Intel JWebEngine (which might be what you are already looking for) documentation says:

> What are the advantages versus the built-in Java HTML editor?
>
> The built-in Java HTML editor of Java is very limited. It only
>   supports HTML 3.2 with some features of HTML 4 and CSS. The support of
>   CSS is wrong in many cases, especially when it comes to cascading
>   selectors. The text is often too small and on many web sites Java only
>   shows an error instead of a incorrectly formatted page.
>
> Here are some further differences:
>
> - JWebEngine can display the ACID 1 test correctly - Java does not
> - JWebEngine can display the ACID 2 test partly - Java only displays a
>     blank page because an error occurs
> - JWebEngine basically shows HTML pages like a browser with JavaScript disabled
> - In cases where the CSS
>     and HTML specifications are not explicit about implementation
>     JWebEngine is designed to mirror Mozilla FireFox's behavior.

Comment: Everything I mentioned is Swing compatible. The problem is not with Swing, it's with the HTML \ CSS related classes (e.g. the link in my answer). The question is about Swing, but I don't see why it would restrict to SE as it is included in EE also.

Comment: com.inet.html.css.HTML.Attribute sounds interesting. Have you implemented something working with it?

Comment: Nope, never needed anything more than the standard Jave SE libraries have.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry, i should have defined whether it was swing or not. Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

No it just understands basic HTML 4.
You could use a [JavaFx WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) inside a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html)